# Graphics driver problem on Asus X200m running 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel-graphics

I recently purchased a new Asus X200m that is as far as I can tell running Integrated Intel® HD Graphics (according to Asus's website). I performed a clean install off a usb of 12.04 which I can confirm is fully functional from having used it without fuss to put 12.04 on my desktop. The computer gets to the purple splash screen and hangs so I have gone in through GRUB and it can load Ubuntu if I boot it through recovery mode although the resolution is locked at 800x600. The drivers are also misreporting as as Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300). I have tried sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel which delivers the response that I am already running the latest version. I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point and way out of my depth. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a ASUS X200m, but I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.  Had a similar issue which I have just resolved.  Updated to new kernel in February and as soon as I restarted, just got a black screen.  Had to connect external monitor and install GRUB customizer via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

And set it to show the GRUB screen on each boot so that I could use an older kernel that functioned properly with my display.  I went through that for months asking the community for help...
Ended up, last night, removing all but the newest and the functioning kernel, following instructions outlined here:
[Remove Old Kernels in Ubuntu](http://tuxtweaks.com/2009/12/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu/)

Today I installed package the package `linux-firmware-nonfree` and

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Which updated my kernel once more and the package `linux-firmware`.

Rebooted and the newest kernel booted up with no display problems...
Not sure which step did the trick but thought I should let you know.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it's due to the graphics driver being broken in recent kernels. I found a work around that recommended installing the mainline kernel 3.11.5-saucy and booting that instead. It works but grub breaks every time so it's necessary to edit the grub file so that it boots by default to 3.11.5 and not another kernel.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D

Download the kernel, unzip the directory and install using the dpkg command (dpkg -i) [dpkg -i filename]. Then sudo update-grub. (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-grub.8.html)

Afterwards, you'll need elevated privileges, running as root. Copy the grub.cfg file, save it as another file name (e.g. grub-new.cfg), edit this grub-new file by removing all kernels listed except 3.11.5. Rename grub.cfg as something else (e.g. grub-original.cfg). Rename grub-new.cfg as grub.cfg. Then reboot the machine. It should work fine. Just beware that any kernel updates will break grub!